# Comparing property of explicitly unwrapped enum type to constant

Tags: swift, enums, option-type

I have an enum difened like this:

```
enum MyEnumType{
case Case1
case Case2
}
```

and a property defined like this:

```
var myProperty:MyEnumType!
```

...declared as an optional type, because my code logic mandates that it can only be set **after** instance initialization.

In one of my methods, I am trying to compare the property to one of the type's preset values (cases), like this:

```
if myProperty == .Case1 {
    // some code
}
```

However, the compiler complains with:

> Could not find member "Case1"

...until I add the `!` to the variable, like this:

```
if myProperty! == .Case1 {
    // some code
}
```

Makes sense that there is no memebr `.Case1` in the type `MyEnumType!`(optional) : `.Case1` it is a value of the type MyEnumType (non-optional - technically **they are two separate types**).

However, what is the point (i.e., convenience) of using an explicitly unwrapped optional (`!` instead of `?` in the declaration), if I still have to append the `!` when I acces it?

**EDIT:** I only need to append the `!` in the comparison (`==`). for example, the following (assignment) code compiles without problem:

```
myProperty = .Case1
```

**EDIT 2:** OK, so here are the actual type names / variable names (it is not confidential or anything) just to make sure I didn't change anyhting in the adaptation for the question:

The type:

```
enum OrderingDirection : Printable {    
    case Ascending
    case Descending

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Ascending:
            return "Ascending"    
        case .Descending:
            return "Descending"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my class's property declaration:

```
var orderDirection:OrderingDirection!
```

...And here is the if block where I try to compare the explicitly-unwrapped optional to one of the type's cases:

```
if orderDirection! == .Ascending { // Compiler error if I omit the "!"
    orderDirection = .Descending
}
else{
    orderDirection = .Ascending
}
```

(I am just toggling the value)

**EDIT 3:** As suggested by @user2194039, I tried **not** omitting the enum type in the comparison: I replaced

`if orderDirection == .Ascending {`

with:

`if orderDirection == OrderingDirection.Ascending {`

...and now the error is gone (no more need for the unwrapping `!`). As a side note, adding the `!` anyway does not generate any warning.

**EDIT 4:** Just to besure, I created a new project, iOS single View Application (Universal, Swift). I modified the included view controller subclass to the following:

```
import UIKit

enum OrderingDirection : Printable {

    case Ascending
    case Descending

    var description: String
        {
            switch self {
            case .Ascending:
                return "Ascending"

            case .Descending:
                return "Descending"
            }
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var orderDirection:OrderingDirection!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if orderDirection == .Ascending { // <- No "!", yet no error

        }
        else{

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

...and, unlike in my actual project, the compiler error is not reported. There must be some interplay with other entities in my code, but right now I can't quite figure out what it might be.

**EDIT 5:** (Further considerations) The followind **does** compile:

```
if orderDirection as OrderingDirection == .Ascending {
```

The following, **does not**:

```
if self.orderDirection == .Ascending {
```

Comment: I updated my test code to use the test in an if statement. It still worked fine. Then I wrapped the property in a class and made the test part of a class method. It still worked fine. As of right now it seems there must be something else involved. I have removed my answer so that your question will continue to get new attention.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder what is the difference between my code and yours. I will create a separate, empty project just to test this with other types/variables and see what happens.

Comment: I have just pasted your code into a fresh playground, still with no issues. I did remove the `!` from `orderDirection` in the `if` test. You should not need to use the `!` there. Can I ask what version of Xcode you are using?

Comment: Weird... I am using the latest(?) 6.4

Comment: Do you still get a compiler error if you replace `if orderDirection! == .Ascending` with `if orderDirection == OrderingDirection.Ascending` and try that? Note I removed the `!` from the comparison and specified the `OrderingDirection` enum along with the specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still get a compiler error if you replace

```
if orderDirection! == .Ascending {...}
```

with

```
if orderDirection == OrderingDirection.Ascending {...}
```

and try that? Note I removed the `!` from the comparison and specified the `OrderingDirection` enum along with the specific case.

If that does eliminate the error, there must be some reason for the compiler's confusion. Do you have more than one Enum with a case named `Ascending`? Is the Enum part of a framework or library or something?

Comment: I also though that there might be something "shadowing" happening, but I searched my whole project and there is no other variable named `orderDirection`, nor any other enum type with a case named `.Ascending`.

Comment: I will wait for a while just in case somebody else sheds some light. If nothing comes up, I'll accept your answer becasue, even though it is just a workaround, it does solve the problem.